# How to get precise Angular compatibility table for Safari browser?

Tags: angular, safari, compatibility

On the Angular IO browser compatibility pages(*) there is a statement:

> Safari    -   2 most recent major versions

Problem is that as of today (2022-08-04) "2 most recent major versions" are 14 and 15.

And I see the same statement for Angular from 5 to 13 and newest 14.

However, what "2 most recent major versions" of Safari was in the time of the release of the Angular: 5, 6, ..., 12 and 13?

I am not sure, but Angular v5 was released on November 1, 2017. On October 31, 2017 was released Safari 11.0.1. It means that in the time of Angular v5 Safari 10 and 11 were "2 most recent major versions", what is not 14 or 15, or I miss something?

Is it possible to get explicit list of versions for every Angular release?

This kind of clear table I see for Angular version 4   - [Angular v4 browser compatibility table](https://v4.angular.io/guide/browser-support)

(*) For example:

- [Angular v5 browser compatibility table](https://v5.angular.io/guide/browser-support)
- [Angular v9 browser compatibility table](https://v9.angular.io/guide/browser-support)
- [Angular v12 browser compatibility table](https://v12.angular.io/guide/browser-support)
- [Angular v13 browser compatibility table](https://v13.angular.io/guide/browser-support)

Answer (score 0):

They would probably test the major releases of Safari, so that would be 14 and 15. Refer [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history).

As to your question, since its major release you can take the date of release of the angular version you are using and then get the major release versions of Safari from the above link provided.

The date of writing the article might not be the best measure, but as per the article [here](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support) it would be the two latest releases of safari from when the angular version was released!

Comment: Yes. It is quite manual work. I am comparing release dates from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_(web_framework) with release dates from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history. But this is also not very precise as there is no statement, which browser version was really used for testing.

Comment: @SewerynHabdank-Wojewódzki You could raise an issue on angular github with your pain point, authors might address it! for this this seems to be the best way as far as I know!